# How to adjust the default size of the Javadoc popup window in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have attached some screen dumps in the Javadoc comments of some of my Swing classes and I would like them to be visible when hovering the mouse over the class name.

```
/**
* The panel containing so and so... <br>
* <img src="../doc-files/ThisPanel.png" width=200><br>
*/
```

As there is little text in the description, the initial size of the popup is very small and it must be resized to view the whole image.

Is there a way to have the popup contain the image or at least define its initial dimensions?

Answer (score 6):

Ive never found options for setting default sizes for Javadoc hovers. You can always use the Javadoc view though in Window > Show View  > Javadoc. You can set this size and the Javadoc of the highlighted code will be shown in here.

Comment: This is what I actually ended up using. However, for large images, the view must still be resized or maximized, so it gives no real advantage in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to get the same **workaround** (mentioned by Elliott Hill, because I don't see a solution to this problem, even if I am using Eclipse Mars - 4.5.1):

- Go over a method or press <kbd>F2</kbd> if the caret is on the method name
- Put the mouse over the popup until the buttons will appear
- Click on `@` sign (`Show in Javadoc View`) to open the `Javadoc` view

  [image]
- Click on a new method to update the Javadoc View content

If you use 2 monitors, you can drag & drop the Javadoc tab and make it "full screen" on the second screen.